# making python 3 exception backward compatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, compatibility, python-2.x

What is the backward (2.6 if possible) compatible syntax of this code block (from [PEP 3109](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/)) :

```
try:
   self.spawn(pp_args)
except DistutilsExecError as msg:
   raise CompileError from msg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as you'd come in python-2.x:

```
try:
   self.spawn(pp_args)
except DistutilsExecError as msg:
    print "DistutilsExecError : " + str(DistutilsExecError(msg))
    print
    print "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:"
    raise CompileError
```